# Where is the Baldurs Gate save file located on Android?

Tags: baldurs-gate

I can't find installation folder on Android either. There is no game folder under .../Android/data/com.beamdog.baldursgateenhancededition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location is as should be /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.beamdog....

It is visible  only using a file manager directly on the device, but not accessible from PC.